# Summing whole numbers results in decimals

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I'm attempting to use PROC SQL to sum population counts (i.e., whole numbers) for various age groups and counties:

```
PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE WORK.MALE_POP_SQL00 AS
    SELECT countyname AS CountyName, age_grp AS AgeGroup, SUM(pop00) AS Pop_00
    FROM WORK.INTERCENSAL_M
    GROUP BY countyname, age_grp
    ORDER BY countyname, age_grp;
QUIT;
```

The issue I'm having is that the results given aren't whole numbers:
[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiKol.png)

Worse than that is that rounding often produces counts that don't match their original raw values. For example the last entry - the raw population value for that age group / county is actually 4, but after rounding the value produced by the PROC SQL it's 3.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are you sure your input data doesn't have decimals? You can end up with rounding errors but usually it's really small and that's not what's happening with your data. Can you create a sample data set so we can replicate this issue?

Comment: Sounds like you don't have whole numbers.  Look at the formats on INTERCENSAL_M, see if those are actually whole numbers or if they're just formatted to look like whole numbers.

Comment: @Reeza The [tag:sql] tag edit you approved was incorrect; [tag:sql] only is appropriate if the question is asking about a SQL query that a person unfamiliar with SAS but familiar with SQL could answer ("how do I do this group by" etc.) which has the same answer in SQL Server or Oracle.   This question is clearly not asking about that - it's asking about a question that is SAS specific.  [tag:proc-sql] is acceptable for questions like that, which are specific to SAS's implementation of SQL, though it's questionable whether it's relevant here (but i'll include it for now).

Comment: @Joe Thanks for the clarification, I didn't know that there was a proc-sql one as well :)

Comment: No problem.  I am very wary of using very popular tags ([tag:sql], [tag:r], etc.) because they have a tendency to end up bringing in bad answers by people not realizing what SAS is and treating it like a generic SQL question, since they're so many orders of magnitude more popular of tags.

Answer (score 2):

You most likely don't actually have whole numbers in your data, despite thinking you do. Formats can hide decimals, but they don't change the actual value, and SQL will not preserve the format except in direct select statements with no grouping/etc.

See for example:

```
data my_data;
input age_grp pop_count;
format pop_count 4.0;
datalines;
1 1234.54
2 1624.43
1 14.35
2 1234.11
1 888.88
2 768.48
;;;;
run;

proc sql;
  select age_grp, sum(pop_count) as pop_sum
    from my_data
    group by age_grp;
quit;
```

And age_grp 2 does not add up rounded to the same thing as it adds to unrounded (the rounded values appear to add up to 3626).